# Python. Greedy algorithm, 2 for loops iterating over lists

Tags: python, list, greedy

I am trying to write a greedy algorithm where I have a constraint on how many items I can fit into a box and I have to fit as many items in a box as possible before moving on to the next one (ie maximizing the weight of each box).

I've been trying to solve this by creating two identical lists, let's say `a_list` and `b_list`.

```
a_list = [9, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2]
b_list = [9, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2]
```

The constraint on each box is 10 here, so for example I can only fit the first item (9) into one before moving onto the next box. The following box should contain 8 + 2.

Each box is a list within the main list ie

```
list_ = [[9], [8,2],[6,4].....]
```

I can only move on to next box once the current one cannot have further items fitted into it.

When I am trying iterate through the two lists I don't know how to delete items to avoid them appearing multiple times in `list_`.

I'm close but I have a couple of items coming up twice while one doesn't come up at all.

It is also the case that despite my sorting the lists in descending order, not all my boxes are optimal, one of them only has one item with value '2' in it. I know it's to do with the loop but I don't understand why it's not going through the items in descending order.

```
limit = 10
list_ = [[]]

for i in a_list:
   for j in b_list:            

       if sum(l[-1]) + i + j <= limit:

           l[-1].append(i)
           l[-1].append(j)
           b_list.remove(j)

       elif sum(l[-1]) + j <= limit:
           l[-1].append(j)
           b_list.remove(j)

       else:
           l.append([])
```

Comment: The essential problem is that you are iterating through a list while removing items from it. Always avoid that.

Comment: Understand, thank you. I've been deleting items only from the inner loop, not the outer. Is that still an issue?

Comment: How many boxes are there?

Comment: As few as possible, I need to maximise the number of items in each box and the number of boxes depends on the value (weight) of the items.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I think that you're using an `a_list` and a `b_list` is that you assume you need to pick two items per box, which need not be the case.

I think you should use a single list, and use a list index based approach to track which items are added.

You also will have issues with deletes, so try setting items that are added to -1 and filter them out after each pass, to avoid confusions with deletes while looping.

I'm resisting sharing the solution code here, but ping me if you need it.

Comment: Thanks Bitonator, much appreciate it. The reason I've been using two lists is that I've been trying to work out how I should iterate further down the list to append items that are smaller in value. Example: when I'm descending from 9, 8, 7 etc, sometimes I need to get to a '2' in order to fill the box.

Comment: ok, so instead, in each pass, try to add as many items into the box as you can, and once you're done, do another pass to delete those items

Comment: I'm probably missing something, apologies. By deleting items in the inner loop, isn't what I've been doing when you say I should make another pass to delete items I had added?

Comment: If you delete items inside the loop, some items will get skipped...lets say, you're at index 2 and you delete, then the item at index 3 moves to index 2, but the next iteration of the loop moves to index 3, skipping an item, so its safer to delete items after you've made a pass through the list

Comment: Thanks! I had thought it only applied to the outer loop but yes I see the point. I'll change my code, thanks! edit: I've already updated it and I see what you mean exactly, thanks!

Comment: cool, so when you do that, you'll also realize you don't need that two lists, the outer loop just needs to keep going until all items have been put into boxes

Answer (score 0):

Changing a list as you iterate over it is always a challenge.  Here is one solution that uses a `while` loop, which I generally don't endorse, but it is a simple enough algorithms that it should work here with no issues.

The `while` loop checks if there are any elements left in the initial list.  It then pops (removes and saves) the first element of the list and iterates over the rest of the list looking for additional elements that satisfy the condition of the summing to less than the constraint.  If an element is found it is appended to sub-list and its index is recorded.  At the end of the for loop the sub list is append to the output list and then recorded indices are removed **in the reverse order**.

```
a_list = [9, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2]
constraint = 10

out = []
while a_list:
    # grab first element of a_list and reset the list of  
    # to pop from a_list to pop from a_list
    sub_out = [a_list.pop(0)]
    pop_list = []

    for i,a in enumerate(a_list):
        if a+sum(sub_out) <= constraint:
            sub_out.append(a)
            pop_list.append(i)

    # append the sub_list to the output list
    out.append(sub_out)
    # remove each item in the pop_list in the reverse order 
    for i in reversed(pop_list):
        a_list.pop(i)

#output:
>>> out
[[9], [8, 2], [6, 4], [3, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not crazy about while loops either but it's exactly what I've been playing around with the last half an hour. Just tried your code on a different list and it's perfect. Much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome.  Don't forget to mark the question as answered if you feel this solution is complete.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, since you ask: the original example was based on a dictionary (ie {x:9, z:7, etc) and not a list and I am supposed to append the keys in the final list of lists, not the values (ie [[x], [y, z]], etc). I used the values in my original post because it was easy but I'm not sure what to replace the 'enumerate' method with in your example if I need to pop keys, not values. Is there an equivalent I can use to iterate through the keys while noting their value? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful. I was struggling to achieve it with generator but then I was missing values later. So simple yet so cool just to initiate sub_out by popping first element out!